# Increasing initrd.gz size prevents kernel from booting

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, u-boot

I have an ARM based embedded system with 1GB of memory.  The kernel, dtb file and root filesystem (initrd.gz) are stored in a FIT file in flash.  U-boot loads the FIT into ram and boots the kernel.

I'm having a problem where if I slightly increase the size of my root file system my system no longer boots and I can't figure out where I'm exceeding a memory boundary.

This configuration works (initrd.gz size ~30MB) u-boot output:

```
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x20683744
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Ramdisk to 8e1d0000, end 8ffffebd ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8e1bf000, end 8e1cf118 ... OK
```

Kernel output:

```
[    2.761235] RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
[    5.345119] EXT4-fs (ram0): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
```

After increasing the size of initrd.gz this configuration doesn't work (initrd.gz size ~35MB):

```
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x20683744
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Ramdisk to 8dfc1000, end 8ffff795 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8dfb0000, end 8dfc0118 ... OK
```

This is the Kernel error I get when trying to use the larger initrd.gz:

```
[    2.781244] RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
[    5.731423] RAMDISK: EOF while reading compressed data
[    5.739401] uncompression error
[    6.192160] EXT4-fs (ram0): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[    6.200144] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 1:0.
[    6.207089] EXT4-fs error (device ram0): ext4_lookup:1576: inode #2: comm swapper/0: deleted inode referenced: 64974
[    6.218882] EXT4-fs (ram0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[    6.225112] devtmpfs: error mounting -117
```

I have 1GB of ram starting at 0x80000000 and U-boot detects the right amount of memory:

```
DRAM:  already initialized, 1 GiB (capacity:1024 MiB, VGA:0 MiB), ECC off
```

Kenel config of ramdisk size:

```
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_COUNT=1
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE=256000
```

Full U-boot and Kernel Log:

```
U-Boot SPL 2019.04 (Nov 24 2021 - 18:02:33 +0000)
Trying to boot from RAM


U-Boot 2019.04 (Nov 24 2021 - 18:02:33 +0000)

UnKnow-SOC: 5010203
RST: Power On
eSPI Mode: SIO:Enable : SuperIO-2e
Eth: MAC0: RMII/NCSI, MAC1: RMII/NCSI, MAC2: RMII/NCSI, MAC3: RMII/NCSI
Model: Aspeed BMC
DRAM:  already initialized, 1 GiB (capacity:1024 MiB, VGA:0 MiB), ECC off
PCIE-0: Link down
MMC:
sdhci_slot0@100: 1, emmc_slot0@100: 0
Loading Environment from SPI Flash... SF: Detected mt25ql02g with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 4 KiB, total 256 MiB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial@1e784000
Out:   serial@1e784000
Err:   serial@1e784000
Model: Aspeed BMC
adc 15 value = 0x385
board_rev: 3
Net:
Warning: ftgmac@1e660000 (eth0) using random MAC address - 12:2c:e3:e4:22:c7
eth0: ftgmac@1e660000
Warning: ftgmac@1e680000 (eth1) using random MAC address - fa:38:94:5e:b7:43
, eth1: ftgmac@1e680000
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 20100000 ...
   Using 'conf-1' configuration
   Trying 'kernel-1' kernel subimage
     Description:  Linux kernel
     Type:         Kernel Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x201000cc
     Data Size:    5780952 Bytes = 5.5 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: 0x80008000
     Entry Point:  0x80008000
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
## Loading ramdisk from FIT Image at 20100000 ...
   Using 'conf-1' configuration
   Trying 'ramdisk-1' ramdisk subimage
     Description:  RAMDISK
     Type:         RAMDisk Image
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x206908e0
     Data Size:    35515536 Bytes = 33.9 MiB
     Architecture: ARM
     OS:           Linux
     Load Address: unavailable
     Entry Point:  unavailable
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
## Loading fdt from FIT Image at 20100000 ...
   Using 'conf-1' configuration
   Trying 'fdt-1' fdt subimage
     Description:  Flattened Device Tree blob
     Type:         Flat Device Tree
     Compression:  uncompressed
     Data Start:   0x20683754
     Data Size:    53529 Bytes = 52.3 KiB
     Architecture: ARM
   Verifying Hash Integrity ... OK
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x20683754
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Ramdisk to 8de21000, end 8ffffc90 ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8de10000, end 8de20118 ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.1.3 (aaron@aaron-VirtualBox) (gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC)) #20 SMP Wed Jan 5 14:22:25 CST 2022
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: AST2620 PSC
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0xbf000000
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x9c/0x4e0 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 17 pages/cpu s39820 r8192 d21620 u69632
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 243712
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyS4,115200n8 root=/dev/ram rw
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 911132K/983040K available (8192K kernel code, 512K rwdata, 1892K rodata, 1024K init, 194K bss, 55524K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 28861 entries in 57 pages
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] scu-irq controller registered, irq 17
[    0.000000] scu-irq controller registered, irq 18
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 1200.00MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x114c1bbbeec, max_idle_ns: 440795229572 ns
[    0.000006] sched_clock: 56 bits at 1200MHz, resolution 0ns, wraps every 2199023255551ns
[    0.000015] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 0ns
[    0.001364] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 2400.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=12000000)
[    0.001381] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001584] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001598] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.002112] *** VALIDATE proc ***
[    0.002213] *** VALIDATE cgroup1 ***
[    0.002224] *** VALIDATE cgroup2 ***
[    0.002234] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.002522] /cpus/cpu@0 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.002538] /cpus/cpu@1 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.002549] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 15, mpidr 80000f00
[    0.003326] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100060
[    0.003436] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.004015] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.004543] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 15, mpidr 80000f01
[    0.004678] smp: Brought up 1 node, 2 CPUs
[    0.004690] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (4800.00 BogoMIPS).
[    0.004695] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.005462] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.015183] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.015413] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.015436] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.016155] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.016780] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.017796] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.019143] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.019159] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.034904] i2cg - base_clk0 : 1000000
[    0.034974] i2cg - base_clk1 : 4000000
[    0.035007] i2cg - base_clk2 : 10000000
[    0.035030] i2cg - base_clk3 : 33333333
[    0.035059] i2c global registered
[    0.052820] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.053173] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.053462] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.053527] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.053629] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.053777] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.056747] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.102558] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.103052] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
[    0.103077] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.103136] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.103232] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.103337] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.103383] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.103595] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.104121] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.104133] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.104138] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.104142] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.104365] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.104959] rootfs image is not initramfs (no cpio magic); looks like an initrd
[    0.230086] Freeing initrd memory: 34684K
[    0.232404] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
[    0.232955] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.233298] jffs2: version 2.2. (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    0.238540] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[    0.238631] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 249)
[    0.240354] PCIE- Link down
[    0.240394] aspeed-pcie 1e6ed200.pcie: host bridge /ahb/apb/pcie@1e6ed2000 ranges:
[    0.240439] aspeed-pcie 1e6ed200.pcie:    IO 0x00010000..0x0001ffff -> 0x00010000
[    0.240463] aspeed-pcie 1e6ed200.pcie:   MEM 0x70000000..0x7ffffffe -> 0x70000000
[    0.240601] aspeed-pcie 1e6ed200.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.240615] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    0.240625] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xffff] (bus address [0x10000-0x1ffff])
[    0.240634] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x70000000-0x7ffffffe]
[    0.244693] PCI: bus0: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    0.246332] aspeed-kcs-bmc: channel=1 addr=0xca0 idr=0x24 odr=0x30 str=0x3c
[    0.247024] aspeed-kcs-bmc: channel=2 addr=0xca8 idr=0x28 odr=0x34 str=0x40
[    0.247519] aspeed-kcs-bmc: channel=3 addr=0xca2 idr=0x2c odr=0x38 str=0x44
[    0.249831] aspeed_jtag: driver successfully loaded.
[    0.250549] aspeed_mctp: reset.
[    0.251512] aspeed_mctp: driver successfully loaded.
[    0.251843] aspeed_mctp 1e6f9000.mctp: no irq specified
[    0.251924] aspeed_mctp: reset.
[    0.252556] aspeed_mctp: driver successfully loaded.
[    0.253971] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 17 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.259918] rts_gpio: 912
[    0.260616] 1e783000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1e783000 (irq = 55, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    0.261593] 1e784000.serial: ttyS4 at MMIO 0x1e784000 (irq = 56, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    0.963132] printk: console [ttyS4] enabled
[    0.968571] rts_gpio: 913
[    0.971997] 1e78d000.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x1e78d000 (irq = 64, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    0.982439] rts_gpio: 914
[    0.985636] 1e78e000.serial: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x1e78e000 (irq = 65, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    0.996096] rts_gpio: 984
[    0.999323] 1e790000.serial: ttyS5 at MMIO 0x1e790000 (irq = 74, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    1.009701] rts_gpio: 985
[    1.012888] 1e790100.serial: ttyS6 at MMIO 0x1e790100 (irq = 75, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    1.023277] rts_gpio: 986
[    1.026465] 1e790200.serial: ttyS7 at MMIO 0x1e790200 (irq = 76, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    1.036908] rts_gpio: 987
[    1.040107] 1e790300.serial: ttyS8 at MMIO 0x1e790300 (irq = 77, base_baud = 115384) is a 16550A
[    1.066850] timeriomem_rng 1e6e2524.hwrng: 32bits from 0x(ptrval) @ 1us
[    1.075683] brd: module loaded
[    1.085457] loop: module loaded
[    1.102789] aspeed_espi: driver successfully loaded.
[    1.109342] aspeed espi oob loaded
[    1.114069] aspeed espi-flash loaded
[    1.118894] aspeed espi-vw loaded
[    1.123077] no host mapping address
[    1.127638] aspeed espi-peripheral loaded
[    1.133917] Uniform Multi-Platform E-IDE driver
[    1.139157] ide-gd driver 1.18
[    1.143380] aspeed-smc 1e620000.spi: bus_width 4, Using 50 MHz SPI frequency
[    1.151375] aspeed-smc 1e620000.spi: mt25ql02g (262144 Kbytes)
[    1.157905] aspeed-smc 1e620000.spi: CE0 window [ 0x20000000 - 0x30000000 ] 256MB
[    1.166274] aspeed-smc 1e620000.spi: CE1 window [ 0x30000000 - 0x30000000 ] 0MB (disabled)
[    1.175514] aspeed-smc 1e620000.spi: read control register: [406c0641]
[    1.231003] 2 fixed-partitions partitions found on MTD device bmc
[    1.237840] Creating 2 MTD partitions on "bmc":
[    1.242900] 0x000000000000-0x0000000f0000 : "u-boot"
[    1.249735] 0x0000000f0000-0x000000100000 : "u-boot-env"
[    1.258061] fmc_spi 1e631000.spi: controller is unqueued, this is deprecated
[    1.265961] fmc_spi_setup() cs: 0, spi->mode 0 spi->max_speed_hz 10000000 , spi->bits_per_word 8
[    1.275894] spi_ctrl 1000600
[    1.279315] fmc_spi 1e631000.spi: fmc_spi : driver loaded
[    1.285718] Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)
[    1.295321] libphy: mdio-aspeed: probed
[    1.317527] libphy: mdio-aspeed: probed
[    1.337571] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.342821] CAN device driver interface
[    1.347342] fmc_spi_setup() cs: 0, spi->mode 0 spi->max_speed_hz 10000000 , spi->bits_per_word 8
[    1.357277] spi_ctrl 1000600
[    1.366718] random: fast init done
[    1.376060] mcp251x spi0.0 can0: MCP2515 successfully initialized.
[    1.383412] ftgmac100 1e660000.ftgmac: Read MAC address 12:2c:e3:e4:22:c7 from chip
[    1.706721] Micrel KSZ9031 Gigabit PHY 1e650000.mdio-1:01: attached PHY driver [Micrel KSZ9031 Gigabit PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=1e650000.mdio-1:01, irq=POLL)
[    1.722810] ftgmac100 1e660000.ftgmac eth0: irq 40, mapped at (ptrval)
[    1.730423] ftgmac100 1e680000.ftgmac: Read MAC address fa:38:94:5e:b7:43 from chip
[    1.966759] random: crng init done
[    2.056721] Micrel KSZ9031 Gigabit PHY 1e650008.mdio-1:02: attached PHY driver [Micrel KSZ9031 Gigabit PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=1e650008.mdio-1:02, irq=POLL)
[    2.072798] ftgmac100 1e680000.ftgmac eth1: irq 41, mapped at 5781ec99
[    2.080378] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    2.087688] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    2.092720] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    2.098831] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.106844] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.114566] aspeed-rtc 1e781000.rtc: registered as rtc0
[    2.120701] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.125785] I2C: i2c-bus [0]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.131948] I2C: i2c-bus [1]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.138084] I2C: i2c-bus [2]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.144187] I2C: i2c-bus [3]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.150371] I2C: i2c-bus [4]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.156494] I2C: i2c-bus [5]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.162623] I2C: i2c-bus [6]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.168811] I2C: i2c-bus [7]: adapter [100 khz]
[    2.175180] dt: /memory node resources: first page r.start=0x80000000, resource_size=0x40000000, PAGE_SHIFT macro=0xc
[    2.187201] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module aspeed-edac controller MIC: DEV 1e6e0000.sdram (INTERRUPT)
[    2.199022] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.205926] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.210801] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.218349] sdhci-aspeed 1e740100.sdhci: Configuring for slot 0
[    2.225083] devm_gpio_request pwr fail
[    2.229396] devm_gpio_request pwr sw fail
[    2.286744] mmc1: SDHCI controller on 1e740100.sdhci [1e740100.sdhci] using PIO
[    2.295792] sdhci-aspeed 1e750100.sdhci: Configuring for slot 0
[    2.356732] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 1e750100.sdhci [1e750100.sdhci] using ADMA
[    2.383950] ASPEED Crypto Accelerator successfully registered
[    2.401745] ASPEED RSA Accelerator successfully registered
[    2.408446] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.414669] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.426826] aspeed_adc: trim 8
[    2.431344] aspeed_adc: cv 6
[    2.435474] aspeed_adc: trim 8
[    2.440023] aspeed_adc: cv 8
[    2.444788] peci-aspeed 1e78b000.peci-bus: peci bus 0 registered, irq 63
[    2.453654] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.459779] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.464342] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.471701] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.476681] can: controller area network core (rev 20170425 abi 9)
[    2.483668] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    2.488654] can: raw protocol (rev 20170425)
[    2.493416] can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20170425 t)
[    2.499747] can: netlink gateway (rev 20170425) max_hops=1
[    2.505935] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[    2.510714] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    2.523358] liteon-pmc pmc: added a shelf FRU device
[    2.583924] mmc0: Tuning failed, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[    2.591583] mmc0: new HS200 MMC card at address 0001
[    2.597851] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 4FPD3R 3.64 GiB
[    2.603214] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 4FPD3R partition 1 4.00 MiB
[    2.610176] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 4FPD3R partition 2 4.00 MiB
[    2.617078] mmcblk0rpmb: mmc0:0001 4FPD3R partition 3 512 KiB, chardev (246:0)
[    2.626207]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3
[    2.776758] liteon-pmc pmc: Driver initialized
[    2.782163] printk: console [netcon0] enabled
[    2.787065] netconsole: network logging started
[    2.792396] aspeed-rtc 1e781000.rtc: hctosys: unable to read the hardware clock
[    2.801284] RAMDISK: gzip image found at block 0
[    2.921922] uncompression error
[    2.972435] EXT4-fs (ram0): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[    2.980416] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 1:0.
[    2.987294] EXT4-fs error (device ram0): ext4_lookup:1576: inode #2: comm swapper/0: deleted inode referenced: 64974
[    2.999086] EXT4-fs (ram0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[    3.005312] devtmpfs: error mounting -117
[    3.012546] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[    3.047716] Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found
[    3.054041] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    3.058946] EXT4-fs error (device ram0): ext4_lookup:1576: inode #2: comm swapper/0: deleted inode referenced: 145588
[    3.070854] Starting init: /sbin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -117)
[    3.079216] Run /etc/init as init process
[    3.083933] EXT4-fs error (device ram0): ext4_lookup:1576: inode #2: comm swapper/0: deleted inode referenced: 16411
[    3.095740] Starting init: /etc/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -117)
[    3.104009] Run /bin/init as init process
[    3.108741] EXT4-fs error (device ram0): ext4_lookup:1576: inode #2: comm swapper/0: deleted inode referenced: 81107
[    3.120551] Starting init: /bin/init exists but couldn't execute it (error -117)
[    3.128827] Run /bin/sh as init process
[    3.133153] EXT4-fs error (device ram0): ext4_lookup:1576: inode #2: comm swapper/0: deleted inode referenced: 81107
[    3.144969] Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -117)
[    3.153044] Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.
[    3.168864] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.1.3 #20
[    3.175465] Hardware name: Generic DT based system
[    3.180806] Backtrace:
[    3.183544] [<8010e5fc>] (dump_backtrace) from [<8010e880>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    3.191993]  r7:809fa93c r6:60000093 r5:00000000 r4:80c6c0a4
[    3.198311] [<8010e860>] (show_stack) from [<808af8ac>] (dump_stack+0x8c/0xa0)
[    3.206373] [<808af820>] (dump_stack) from [<80121b78>] (panic+0x124/0x2f0)
[    3.214139]  r7:809fa93c r6:80c11e84 r5:00000000 r4:80c80648
[    3.220456] [<80121a58>] (panic) from [<808c74b0>] (kernel_init+0x11c/0x124)
[    3.228320]  r3:80c09c48 r2:00000000 r1:3dc34000 r0:809fa93c
[    3.234628]  r7:00000000
[    3.237452] [<808c7394>] (kernel_init) from [<801010e8>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c)
[    3.245896] Exception stack(0xbe0e5fb0 to 0xbe0e5ff8)
[    3.251530] 5fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    3.260654] 5fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    3.269778] 5fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[    3.277154]  r5:808c7394 r4:00000000
[    3.281145] CPU0: stopping
[    3.284164] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.1.3 #20
[    3.290764] Hardware name: Generic DT based system
[    3.296103] Backtrace:
[    3.298832] [<8010e5fc>] (dump_backtrace) from [<8010e880>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    3.307278]  r7:00000000 r6:60000193 r5:00000000 r4:80c6c0a4
[    3.313593] [<8010e860>] (show_stack) from [<808af8ac>] (dump_stack+0x8c/0xa0)
[    3.321653] [<808af820>] (dump_stack) from [<80111668>] (handle_IPI+0x340/0x374)
[    3.329904]  r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:00000004 r4:80c80508
[    3.336219] [<80111328>] (handle_IPI) from [<80102230>] (gic_handle_irq+0x84/0x88)
[    3.344667]  r10:80b5da40 r9:80c00000 r8:80c01ed8 r7:c0803000 r6:c0802000 r5:c080200c
[    3.353401]  r4:80c0a304 r3:80109afc
[    3.357388] [<801021ac>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<80101a6c>] (__irq_svc+0x6c/0x90)
[    3.365733] Exception stack(0x80c01ed8 to 0x80c01f20)
[    3.371365] 1ec0:                                                       00000000 000015f0
[    3.380491] 1ee0: be7b18a0 8011c500 80c00000 00000000 80c09c70 80c09cac 80c71405 80a020d0
[    3.389616] 1f00: 80b5da40 80c01f34 80c01f38 80c01f28 80109afc 80109b00 60000013 ffffffff
[    3.398741]  r9:80c00000 r8:80c71405 r7:80c01f0c r6:ffffffff r5:60000013 r4:80109b00
[    3.407385] [<80109ab8>] (arch_cpu_idle) from [<808ceef4>] (default_idle_call+0x30/0x3c)
[    3.416415] [<808ceec4>] (default_idle_call) from [<80154524>] (do_idle+0xe8/0x168)
[    3.424960] [<8015443c>] (do_idle) from [<80154870>] (cpu_startup_entry+0x28/0x2c)
[    3.433407]  r9:80c80280 r8:80c09c40 r7:80c80280 r6:ffffffff r5:00000001 r4:000000c9
[    3.442049] [<80154848>] (cpu_startup_entry) from [<808c738c>] (rest_init+0xb8/0xc0)
[    3.450691] [<808c72d4>] (rest_init) from [<80b00b94>] (arch_call_rest_init+0x18/0x1c)
[    3.459521]  r5:00000001 r4:80c802d8
[    3.463509] [<80b00b7c>] (arch_call_rest_init) from [<80b0109c>] (start_kernel+0x4a4/0x4e0)
[    3.472827] [<80b00bf8>] (start_kernel) from [<00000000>] (  (null))
[    3.479923] WDT reset called
BP
```

Comment: Please include the full U-Boot and kernel logs, thanks.

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of my post.  Thanks.

Comment: OK.  So, I would add some debug in U-Boot to see that we're setting linux,initrd-start/end correctly, and then that the kernel is seeing that and that it matches.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm currently working on.  I've narrowed down the issue to memmove_wd in common/image.c in u-boot.  My platform is based on the ASPEED SDK and they set #define CONFIG_WDT for the watchdog timer.  This is not checked for in memmove_wd so u-boot attempts to move the entire 35MB buffer in one go.  I've added the check for CONFIG_WDT and now the entire buffer is copied in chunks but now my kernel won't boot.  It's weird that 30MB will copy fine but once I go over that, only 2MB copy to buffer and there is no indication of any watchdog issue.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with memmove_wd when copying chunks.  At every chunk boundary I lose 3 bytes.

Original file:
[00006440  29 78 e6 76 cb 18 a5 6d  d7 6a cf 54 ba d1 84 2a]
[00016440  ae 2d f3 84 b2 21 3a da  69 07 a5 6b 1d 65 78 5b]

Destination Buffer:
[00006440  29 78 e6 76 cb 18 a5 6d  d7 00 00 00 ba d1 84 2a]
[00016440  ae 2d f3 84 b2 00 00 00  69 07 a5 6b 1d 65 78 5b]

Comment: I switched memmove_wd to a simpler front to back copy and that fixed the issue.  See details in the answer below.

Comment: That's very odd indeed.  Do you have hardware you can test this on too, or just the emulator?

Comment: I'm running on hardware.  The hardware has been running fine for over a year.  I'm looking into moving the rootfs from eMMC to SPI flash and that's when I encountered this issue.

Comment: Ah, I thought you mentioned QEMU / emulator earlier.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I found the root cause.  When DMA is enabled for the SPI flash, ASPEED modified memmove to copy on a 4-byte boundary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause of issue:

It looks like ASPEED modified the low level memmove function in /lib/string.c to speed up flash copies.  In their code, count is changed to a 4 byte boundary which breaks the back to front copy from memmove_wd.

```
#ifdef CONFIG_ASPEED_SPI_DMA
    if (dest == src)
        return dest;

    if (
       ((u32)src >= ASPEED_FMC_CS0_BASE)
    && ((u32)src < (ASPEED_FMC_CS0_BASE + 0x10000000))) {
        count = ((count + 3) / 4) * 4;
        aspeed_spi_fastcpy((u32)dest, (u32)src, count);
        return dest;
    }
#endif
```

I switched memmove_wd() in u-boot/common/image.c to a simpler front to back copy and added the check for CONFIG_WDT and everything works now.

```
#if defined(CONFIG_HW_WATCHDOG) || defined(CONFIG_WATCHDOG) || defined(CONFIG_WDT)
{
    while (len > 0)
    {
            size_t chunk = (len > chunksz) ? chunksz : len;
            WATCHDOG_RESET();
            memmove(to, from, chunk);
            to += chunk;
            from += chunk;
            len -= chunk;
    }
```

Another option would be to disable CONFIG_ASPEED_SPI_DMA.